# How to multiply a vector from the left side with matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, products

I have always dealt with vector - matrix multiplication where the vector is the right multiplicand, but I am not sure how to apply the product between a matrix and a vector when the vector is the left multiplicand.

I have the following example

$$\beta = \begin{pmatrix} \beta_0 & \beta_1 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 2}$$

and a general matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$$

What would be the algorithm to multiply $\beta \cdot A$? Of course the result is a $1 \times 2$ row vector.

Comment: It would be $(\beta_{0}a_{11}+\beta_{1}a_{21}~~~~~\beta_{0}a_{12}+\beta_{1}a_{22})$

Comment: To add to the other answers, If the vector is on the right, the product is a projection of the vector onto the rows of the matrix. If the vector is on the left, the result is a projection of the vector onto the columns of the matrix. Cheers!

Comment: Just to verify the rows in the matrix represent obe vector each right not the columns of the matrix..since you are doing a dot product that wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So essentially you wish to compute:
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_0&\beta_1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This equals the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}\beta_0+a_{21}\beta_1&a_{12}\beta_0+a_{22}\beta_1
\end{pmatrix} .
$$
Hopefully it is clear how the multiplication works.

Answer (score 7):

Matrix multiplication is defined so that the entry $(i,j)$ of the product is the dot product of the left matrix's row $i$ and the right matrix's column $j$.

If you want to reduce everything to matrices acting on the left, we have the identity $xA = \big(A^Tx^T\big)^T$ where $T$ denotes the transpose. This is because $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$, and the operation that sends a matrix to its transpose is self-inverse.

Comment: The vector gets transposed too: if you have $1 \times 2$ vector $x$, when you transpose, you'll have a $2 \times 1$ vector $x^T$.